# Automatic resolve nuget reference of dynamic loaded assembly

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-assembly

how can i auto resolve nuget packages of a dynamic loaded assembly.
I have a Environment assembly with interfaces, and a assembly with an implementation. I load the implementation dynamically, but it doesn't resolve a nuget reference of the implementation assembly, because it`s not in the output-folder.
Can i (just while debugging) load the assembly from C:\Users[Username].nuget\packages?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link to some docs on How to load an assembly at runtime that is located in a folder that is not the bin folder of the application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/837908/how-to-load-an-assembly-at-runtime-that-is-located-in-a-folder-that-is).

It lists 3 options

1. Install assembly in the GAC
2. Use an application configuration (.config) file with the  tags
3. Use the AssemblyResolve event

These options appear to be relevant for .NET Framework assemblies. If your assembly is .NET Core, then a quick google came up with [this which might help](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194332/WebControls/). It appears to be a .NET Core equivilant of AssemblyResolve, but I only looked at it for 5 seconds.